# Maven build have to run python script to generate a web.xml

Tags: python, maven, exec-maven-plugin

I'm using the exec-maven-plugin and the pom is compiling, but it seems to not execute this plugin when I compile my project:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <executions>
     <execution>
        <configuration>
           <executable>python</executable>
           <workingDirectory>scripts/python/</workingDirectory>
           <arguments>
              <argument>webxmlgen.py</argument>

              <argument>argument1</argument>
              <argument>argument2</argument>
           </arguments>
        </configuration>
        <id>generation</id>
        <phase>generate</phase>
        <goals>
           <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
     </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Did I forget something? I'm also not sure about the phase and the goal I have to use...

**Edit :**

I've deleted the workingDirectory tag and put it directly in the argument and now it works with the phase generate-ressources, thanks !

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <executions>
     <execution>
        <configuration>
           <executable>python</executable>
           <arguments>
              <argument>scripts/python/webxmlgen.py</argument>

              <argument>argument1</argument>
              <argument>argument2</argument>
           </arguments>
        </configuration>
        <id>generation</id>
        <phase>generate-ressources</phase>
        <goals>
           <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
     </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

`phase` tells Maven when to execute it and `goal` tells it which target to invoke on the plugin when the phase is reached.

Your problem is that there is no `generate` phase. [Here is a list](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.0/maven-core/lifecycles.html). Try `generate-resources` instead.